# PHP Identify HTML tags and square bracker placeholders found in Wordpress blog posts

Tags: wordpress, parsing, tags

I am migrating a site from Wordpress to a bespoke platform (already created by a previous developer). The existing wordpress blog appears to have allowed the admin to paste in HTML code so I've spotted from a quick glance some iframes, images etc.

I need to update the new blog to support the existing HTML content where it's been used.
There are also some Wordpress square bracket placeholders - e.g.

```
[caption id="attachment_1281" align="aligncenter" width="350"]
```

There are hundreds of posts so looking through them manually is not really sensible...

I need to loop through all the posts in the wp_posts table and identify any other HTML elements used. I know RegEx is generally frowned upon for working with HTML - but not sure what the best approach here is.

I've got to a stage of pulling all the "published" posts out of WP into a database, but how would you suggest parsing the 'content' field and identifying all html tags and these square bracket tags?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right about the regex here. For the brackets I see no other choice. HTML we can use a loop hole for it.

The problem is going to be "rogue" brackets. So you need to come up with an function to check if the bracket is actually part of a tag structure or just somewhere in the page.

This function should get you on the road:

```
function findSquareBracketsAndHTML()
{
    //this beautiful regex matches [...] 99% of all cases, for 100% isn't viable is guess.
    $bracketElements = preg_match('/\[/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|\'.*?\'|[^\'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?\]/', $contentField, $matches);
    //$matches contains all [] elements.    

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($contentField) //you might need to wrap this in a container element.

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $nodes = $xpath->query('//*');

     foreach($nodes as $node) {
           //do whatever you want with html nodes here
     }

}
```